# How should I return errors in asp .net core API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'am working on my private project using .Net Core and Angular and i have a little pickle with how should I return errors.

My backend has layers(controllers, services, repositories and entity).
I've created general response object I want to return. In my service method I set different errors like "NotFound" or "Internal server error" as a StatusCode.

I don't want to do switch case on StatusCode and return different error based on that in controller because I don't think it's a good solution.
Returning ApiResponse object will cause that I always will have 200 code and to know if there's any error I need to check the status code of the returned object in the Angular. I don't know if that's a good solution.

And I want to keep these layers. I want controller to just handle the request, service to have all the logic and repository to do CRUD actions.

So how should I return errors from my service layer to controller?

That's one version of my controller method.

```
    [Authorize]
    [ApiValidationFilter]
    [HttpPost("updateFacebookUrl/")]
    public async Task<ApiResponse> UpdateFacebookURL([FromBody] UpdateURLVm updateURLVm)
    {
      return await _userInfoService.UpdateFacebookURL(updateURLVm);
    }
```

And that's second version of my controller method.

```
    [Authorize]
    [ApiValidationFilter]
    [HttpPost("updateInstagramUrl/")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateInstagramURL([FromBody] UpdateURLVm updateURLVm)
    {
      var result = await _userInfoService.UpdateInstagramURL(updateURLVm);

      if (result.StatusCode != (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
      {
        return BadRequest(result);
      }

      return Ok(result);
    }
```

That's my service method.

```
    public ApiResponse UpdateInstagramURL(UpdateURLVm updateURLVm)
    {
      try
      {
        var user = _unitOfWork.userRepository.FindByCondition(x => x.Id == updateURLVm.UserId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
          return new ApiResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "User not found");

        user.Instagram = updateURLVm.URL;

        _unitOfWork.userRepository.Update(user);
        _unitOfWork.Complete();

        return new ApiResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        return new ApiResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Something went wrong");
      }
    }
```

Return object.

```
 public class ApiResponse
  {
    public int StatusCode { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public object Result { get; private set; }

    public ApiResponse(int statusCode, string message)
        : this(statusCode)
    {
      this.Message = message;
    }

    public ApiResponse(object result) :
      this(200)
    {
      Result = result;
    }

    public ApiResponse(int statusCode)
    {
      this.StatusCode = statusCode;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would say that you can try to introduce some middleware/OnActionExecuted action filter that will analyze IActionResult and set valid status.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that solution.

Comment: yeah I used middleware in the past, I;ll post my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd throw exception in my core service or repository and let middleware handle it.
ApiError is my custom class and some things might not be the same as this was written with .NET Core 2.2 I imagine you are using 3.x. And a quick note (if I may) those api endpoint urls are not very RESTful..

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.Run(async context => {
                var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
                if (ex?.Error is NullReferenceException)
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                else if (ex?.Error is InvalidOperationException)
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                else
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 500;

                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                ApiError error = new ApiError()
                {
                    Code = context.Response.StatusCode,
                    Message = env.IsDevelopment() ? ex?.Error.Message : "An unexpected error happened. Try again later."
                };

                await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error)).ConfigureAwait(false);
            });
        });
   }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. That's exactly what I was looking for.

And as for the endpoints I'm right now in the middle of restructuring my entire backend. This project was my diploma project and now I want to continue this but I'm trying to use more design patterns, better techniques, solutions etc. I'm want this project to be kind of "show off" project for job interview or something :). And I want to learn as much as I can while working on it.